# Porcentaje de carga de archivos con ng-file-upload AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, progressbar

Estoy usando [ng-file-upload](https://github.com/danialfarid/ng-file-upload) para carga un archivo, actualmente puedo ver el porcentaje en consola con un `console.log()`, pero el console está en el service y no se como pasarlo al controller (sin hacer el return) para mostrarlo en HTML. El código que tengo es el siguiente:

En el Controller:

```
factorService.subirArchivo($scope.campo1, $scope.campo2, file).then(
    function(response){
       ...
    });
```

En el Service:

```
this.subirArchivo = function (campo1, campo2, , file) {   
        var promise = Upload.upload({
            url: "subirArchivo.php",
            method: 'post',
            file: file,
            data: {
                liderComunitario: lider,
                barrio: barrio,
                fechaReporte: fechaReporte
            }
        }).then(function (resp) {
            return resp;
        }, function (resp) {
            console.log('Error status: ' + resp.status);
        }, function (evt) {
            var progressPercentage = parseInt(100.0 * evt.loaded / evt.total);
            console.log('progress: ' + progressPercentage + '% ' + 
            evt.config.data.file.name);
        });
        return promise;
    };
```

En la parte final del service está el `console.log` que muestra el porcentaje por consola y funciona correctamente, el problema es mostrarlo en HTML, alguna idea?

Comment: que tal con progress tu progressPercentage es entero, entonces no habra problema si lo pasas como valor al control, ejemplo: <progress value="25" max="100">
</progress>

Comment: leer mas: https://css-tricks.com/html5-progress-element/

Comment: El problema esta en que lleguen los datos al HTML después es pan comido,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema esta en que debes usar 'promise' para retornar el valor:

```
this.subirArchivo = function (campo1, campo2, , file) {   
    //Inicializamos el constructor
    var defer = $q.defer();

    var promise = Upload.upload({
        url: "subirArchivo.php",
        method: 'post',
        file: file,
        data: {
            liderComunitario: lider,
            barrio: barrio,
            fechaReporte: fechaReporte
        }
    }).then(function (resp) {
        //return resp; En lugar de retornarlo se encapsula
        defer.resolve(resp);
    }, function (resp) {

        console.log('Error status: ' + resp.status);
        // Encapsulamos el error
        defer.reject(errorMsg);

    }, function (evt) {
        var progressPercentage = parseInt(100.0 * evt.loaded / evt.total);
        console.log('progress: ' + progressPercentage + '% ' + 
        evt.config.data.file.name);
        //encapsulamos el progreso
        defer.notify(progressPercentage);
    });

     return defer.promise;
};
```

En el controlador procesamos la promesa

```
factorService.subirArchivo($scope.campo1, $scope.campo2, file)
    .then(
           function(response){
              //Respuesta satisfactoria
           }, function(error){
              // Se captura el posble error
           }, function(notify){
              //Procesamos la notificacion.
           });
```

Te adjunto la documentación oficial del constructor $q, deferred y promise.

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q